# Why doesn't std::to_string support container classes as input?

Tags: c++, stl

So std::to_string works on various primitive types. However, when trying to print the elements of a container like a vector, I have to iterate through the vector element by element and print each individually. Now granted, with something like a vector this can amount to a single statement or loop like such:

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int x) {cout << x <<", "; });
```

but with other container classes it can be quite a nuisance to format the data type.

In contrast, languages like Java or Python have functions that print most containers in a single statement. Why doesn't STL accept these as arguments in std::to_string or implement to_string as member function of the container classes?

Comment: The code you’ve shown will work for any container. But note that it writes a comma and a space after the last element.

Comment: An `ostream_iterator` helps with that trailing delimiter issue, btw.

Comment: What format should `to_string` print in? A pair of square brackets and a comma delimited list? Something Json like? Maybe pretty print? The standard library is meant to provide utility to as wide a range of applications as possible. Printing a container is too niche. Rolling out your own for your own needs is not too hard, so there is no need for a standard library solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector doesn't know how to convert custom class to string, unless custom classes provide string conversion. Now custom classes are not required to provide string conversion because it might be meaning less for that class.

Containers are very generic in that sense.
And like you pointed, its very easy to implement. Very typical way is to overload `<<` operator as follows:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& cout, const vector<int>& sorted)
{
  cout << "Array => ";
  for( auto i : sorted ) {
    cout << i << ", ";
  }
  cout << endl;
  return cout;
}
```

Or use `stringstream` class or use `for_each` ...